# Determining number of functions on set $\{1,\ 2,\ 3,\ ...,\ 20\}$ with given condition

Tags: combinatorics, functions

> The number of functions $f$ from $\{1,\ 2,\ 3,\ ...,\ 20\}$, onto $\{1,\ 2,\ 3,\ ...,\ 20\}$ such that $f(k)$ is multiple of $3$, wherever $k$ is a multiple of $4$, is :

My attempt to solve the problem

I am writing the condition given in question again,

If $k\in\{4,\ 8,\ 12,\ 16,\ 20\}\implies f(k)\in\{3,\ 6,\ 9,\ 12,\ 15,\ 18\}$

In a function any element in domain can only have a single image in codomain but two or more elements can have a common image.

Since multiples of $4$ i.e. $\{4,\ 8,\ 12,\ 16,\ 20\}$ can only have a image in the set $\{3,\ 6,\ 9,\ 12,\ 15,\ 18\}$

So, number of ways in which multiples of $4$ can have image in codomain is

$$(\mathrm{number\ of\ multiples\ of}\ 3)^{(\mathrm{number\ of\ multiples\ of}\ 4)}=6^5$$

Similarly the number of ways remaining numbers can have image in codomain is $20^{15}$, So total number of functions become $6^5\times20^{15}$

But the answer given is $(15)!\times6!$, which I got when assuming $f$ as one-one function but it is not mentioned in question so I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: the question mentions "onto" which means that $f$ should be surjective. Since this is a function between two finite sets of the same cardinality, it is equivalent to saying that $f$ is one-one.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I don't think "onto" is at right place in the question. According to me "onto" here means that $f$ is defined from $\{1,2,3,...,20\}\ \mathrm{to\ }\{1,2,3,...,20\} $. Forgive me if I didn't understand language of question well.

Comment: No, it does mean the function is onto.

Comment: The phrase "$f$ is a function from $A$ onto $B$" is indeed used to mean that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani My book didn't mention it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose both domain and the codomain are finite with same number of elements, say n. Suppose the function is onto.Then it has to be one one as well. If nit, then there are two elements x,y in the domain such that their image is same, say a. Now in the domain, you have n-2 elements left and in the codomain ,you have n-1 elements. Each point in the domain can have only one image. Hence at least one element in the codomain will be left out without a pre-image, a contradiction to the onto nature of the function. Hence the function must be one one as well.

Remember that finiteness is important here. You can have counterexamples if the sets are not finite. Example, take domain and codomain to be N, the set of natural numbers. Map 1 and 2 to 1. Then map rest of the numbers X to x-1. Then the map is onto, but not one one.